# life cycle of a Java EE application using struts 2, spring 3, hibernate 3, eclipse and SQL server

Tags: struts2, spring-3, hibernate3

I'm a newer java/Java EE application programmer :

The aim of my question that i found a tutorial or a refcard talking about integration of struts 2, spring 3, hibernate 3 under a Java EE project( the database doesn't matter and the eclipse version too) wich explain the role of each configuration file( such as web.xml, application-context.xml, struts.xml) and what you have to put inside. i hope that it gives the process that porsuit a request from the User Interface to the data layer and the role of the configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note sure what exactly is your question but here is a quick answer to your question

- Struts2 will be used as MVC (Model View Controller). i.e the framework will be used to create UI and will be responsible to take user inputs and showing the output to the user in a very smile words.
- Spring in itself start from DI to Web-services, AOP,Talking to Hibernate and many more, it all depedends upon what all features you want to use. in S2 the typical use of Spring is DI.You can also use Spring in your service layer
- Hibernate is a part of ORM layer and will be responsible for interacting with your underlying database.you can use Spring to interact with your ORM layer or can develop independent ORM layer using hibernate.Struts2 has nothing to do with hibernate.

here is a quick tutorial for the same [struts-2-spring-jpa](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/struts-2-spring-2-jpa-ajax.html). You can find more tutorial by simple googling